# There is nothing changed, but eclipse egit marks the file as changed

Tags: git, egit

I'm using eclipse egit with github. I found something strange that I didn't change anything, but egit marked the file as "changed". See the images:

1. the file "run.bat" is marked as "changed"

   [image]
2. Compare with "file in Git index", you can see nothing is different

   [image]
3. Compare with "file in HEAD", you can see nothing is different neither

   [image]

My friend uses mac and I use windows, but we all configured git as "commit unix lineend".. I also checked the lineend of my source and the HEAD, they are the same(I configured git to convert them to "\r\n" when pulling)

Where is wrong? Is it a bug of Egit?

Comment: Check line endings - CR, CR-LF

Comment: "I configured git to convert them to "\r\n" when pulling": that should be the cause right there, no?

Comment: Looks like you have mixed line endings in one file. Not sure how it would work then. The automatic conversion is hardly predictable for me, I disable it usually...

Answer (score 48, accepted):

One of the first things I've had issues with in Git.

I've said this forever:

```
git config --system core.autocrlf false
```

To get rid of CR highlighting in diff and patch views, use:

```
git config --system core.whitespace cr-at-eol
```

If you share your computers with others, replace '--system' with '--global'.

Comment: Did not help me. The changes you mention kick in when using git command line, but not for EGit.

Comment: @Ztyx please see my answer, for an EGit solution.

Comment: You should be dropping down to command line to use git. Or get a plugin to eclipse to show a command line.

Answer (score 62):

Eclipse Preferences / Team / Git / Configuration / User Settings

("core" section)

```
key: autocrlf
value: false
```

The key should already exist, so just need to edit the value.

If creating a new key then use `core.autocrlf`.

Comment: This doesn't work for me. The *Location* property shown in the User Settings tab is my global gitconfig (`C:\Users\William\.gitconfig`) and has all the correct settings. However, `git commit -m` works fine while Eclipse's *Commit* option nukes my line endings.

Comment: This helped me, but I had to delete the repo and imported it again.

Comment: Worked once I right-clicked on the project and did `Team->Synchronize Workspace`

Comment: In case the key does not exist, use **Add Entry...** with `core.autocrlf` as key and `false` as value, which also triggers the creation of the **core** section.

Comment: This is not a solution: it disables auto-conversion of line endings, which maybe will fix the comparing issue, but will worsen a lot of other things.

Answer (score 16):

As a follow up, as I just ran into the same issue, another reason for EGit detecting all files as changed is a POSIX file permission problem at least when used together with Cygwin's git.

The following will fix that; however keep in mind that this also means that they are ignored then:

`$ git config core.filemode false`

Comment: Thanks a lot! This also required closing/opening the project.

Comment: That was my issue as well. For now I was able to fix the permissions on the file and commit that.

Comment: this was my issue as well. Thank you so much, the past ONE HOUR searching for solution has paid off!

Answer (score 9):

For eclipse specific issues for linefeed, you can also change the return character in Eclipse Preferences where you can change the New text file line delimiter from Windows syntax to Unix which should help.

[image: Eclipse Next File Line Delimiter settings]

Comment: this is the proper answer with autocrlf set to false

Comment: Changing **just** this preference helped however had to restart my Eclipse after changing that setting. BTW I was facing this problem using Eclipse on Windows 10 and the file being reported as changed on Windows-Eclipse was originally modified on Ubuntu and pushed to remote repo and pulled on Windows machine. Thanks.

Answer (score 8):

you can ignore whitespace differences with Eclipse settings under Compare/Patch.
Preferences-->General-->Compare/Patch,you can find the "Ignore white space" in the right,and select this option.

Comment: as well as: Preferences/Team/Git/[box Revionsion Information]"ignore whitespace changes"

Answer (score 6):

I also have the same issue from the Eclipse git commit is showing this issue

once modified file and finally removed the changes from the file even though it showing the file in **Un staged changes** section.

Solution: 
Eclipse -> Window -> Preferences -> Team -> Git -> Configuration -> User Settings (right side tab)

click on **Add Entry**

```
Key  : core.autocrlf
Value: true
```

click on Ok then click on Apply -> Ok
Refresh your "Git Staging tab" or check the Team -> commit option. now it will only show the exact changes only.

Comment: none of this worked for me on Eclipse. I sort of ran some utility which generated few classes but also, changed some alterations in the existing classes. Now, am having a hell of time in filtering the actual changed files with the spaces ones.

Answer (score 0):

i had the same issue and nothing of the proposed solutions did work. i hat the `autocrlf` feature turned off, the latest version of egit and git installed. the line endings of the repository and local files were both matching.

the problem was caused by an entry in the .gitattributes:

```
* text=auto eol=lf
```

i could therefore:

- remove the attribute
- commit the changes

but what also did work was to go to command line and type

> git reset --hard

and then refresh in eclipse.

Answer (score -4):

In General->Workspace. Select Text encoding UTF-8

Comment: How this will help with line endings issues in eclipse / git?

Comment: Can you please elaborate a bit?

Comment: Have you read the question and answers? How encoding is related to this issue?