# eclipse compare editor stopped showing detailed differences

Tags: eclipse, git, editor, compare

I've been using eclipse for java android development for 6 months and I love the compare editor.  In the last few days I have been hacking away and I think I have all my git ducks in a row, or close enough that things are clean and neat and I can find old working versions of apps.

But it seems in the last day or two, the eclipse compare editor has stopped showing diffs!   i right click on uncommitted PlayThread.java and choose to compare with Commit... or HEAD or branch or anything, and no matter how similar the files might be, the compare editor shows one big white bar on its right side, and clicking to go to the next difference highlights the whole file!

I have looked through the git and compare preferences on eclipse and can't find anything that might help.

Any help getting my beautiful compare editor working for me again would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: possible duplicate of [The is nothing changed, but eclipse egit keep to marked the file as changed](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8227233/the-is-nothing-changed-but-eclipse-egit-keep-to-marked-the-file-as-changed)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Note the latest [EGit 5.3.0 (Feb. 2020, 8 years later)](https://wiki.eclipse.org/EGit/New_and_Noteworthy/5.3#Compare_and_Merge_Editors) improves the right side of the compare editor, using the `Eclipse -> Preferences -> Text Editors -> Show whitespace characters` mentioned in [Vivek](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2065799/vivek)'s [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55310223/6309).

> Text comparisons in Eclipse have been improved to make "Show Whitespace" work in more cases.
>
> Also, concurrent editing of a file in a merge editor and in another editor open on the same file has been improved and works now better and even for files not in the Eclipse workspace.

[image: https://wiki.eclipse.org/images/a/aa/EGit_Compare_Editor_Show_Whitespace.png -- Screenshot of a Java comparison in Eclipse (workspace against index) showing whitespace on the index side]

> **Note that both showing whitespace** and concurrent editing depend not only on the way EGit sets up the comparison (which is what we improved) but also on the actual editors being used. These editors are beyond the control of EGit.
>
> With files not in the Eclipse workspace, one may encounter Platform [bug 214351](https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=214351) when a file is open in another editor.

---

Original answer (May 2012):

> The compare editor shows one big white bar on its right side,

That means EGit considers the local content of that file (on your disk) differs completely from what have been committed.
The one classic case where that happens is for automatic EOL conversion (Windows `<=>` Unix), which is why I always set `core.autocrlf` to `false`.
See "[Git beta on Windows (msysgit) - Unix or DOS line termination](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1249932/git-1-6-4-beta-on-windows-msysgit-unix-or-dos-line-termination/1250133#1250133)".
See also "[Distributing git configuration with the code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2333424/distributing-git-configuration-with-the-code/2354278#2354278)" for managing those EOLs through `.gitattribute` file (except [EGit doesn't support yet `.gitattribute` file](https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=357039)).

---

In this instance, the [OP mwengler](https://stackoverflow.com/users/841828/mwengler) reports:

> Well that was it.
> The way I fixed it was in **`Eclipse > Window > Preferences > General > Compare/Patch > General`** on that page I checked "**`Ignore white space`**" and now the editor shows my diffs.
> But I think I will turn off that `autocrlf` stuff, I don't think I'm using anything on Windows that can't handle both flavors

See [EGit bug 361503](https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=361503) which mentions that this "Ignore White Space" now also honors the `core.autocrlf` setting.

---

[Eclipse 4.29](https://eclipse.dev/eclipse/news/4.29/jdt.php#ignoreWhitespace) (Q3 2023) adds:

> ### Improved "Ignore Whitespace" in Java Compare
>
> Up to now the "Ignore White Space" context menu action in the Java Compare editor ignored all whitespace, including what may be semantically significant whitespace.
>
> [image: Showing all white space changed -- https://eclipse.dev/eclipse/news/4.29/images/show_ws.png]
>
> For example, a white space difference in a Java string literal is semantically significant while trailing white space is not.
>
> This has now been inproved so that e.g. white space changes in string literals are also shown while "Ignore White Space" is active.
>
> [image: Hiding insignificant white space -- https://eclipse.dev/eclipse/news/4.29/images/ignore_ws.png]

Comment: Well that was it.  The way I fixed it was in Eclipse > Window > Preferences > General  > Compare/Patch > General on that page I checked "Ignore white space" and now the editor shows my diffs.  But I think I will turnj off that autocrlf stuff, I don't think I'm using anything on windows that can't handle both flavors.

Comment: @mwengler Ok, I have included your conclusion in the answer, for more visibility, as well as a link explaining how the "Ignore White Space" option is related to `core.autocrlf`.

Answer (score 14):

With respect to Javascript compair showing nothing, there is a known bug.

https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=509820

Workaround...

> - Window >> Preferences >> General Tab >> Compare/Patch
> - Deselect checkbox next to "Open structure compare automatically"

Comment: What is the impact of turning it off. This worked for me.

Comment: Wow, that's an old bug.  Still there.

Comment: Still the same End of 2020

Answer (score 2):

Below setting also works for Eclipse Oxygen Release.

It appears that this has something to do with the Structured Compare.  To

use the simpler and apparently working version of compare choose:

> - Window > Preferences >  General Tab > Compare/Patch
> - Deselect checkbox next to "Open structure compare automatically"

Enjoy text level diffing of ES6 classes.

Regards,
Rasool Javeed Mohammad
javeed.mca@gmail.com

Answer (score 2):

Today again after long I caught in this issue. Every-time I fix this problem and move on but this time I tried understanding the root cause and get it fixed and since the *fix which worked for me is not in the answers to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10457639/eclipse-compare-editor-stopped-showing-detailed-differences) question*, thus adding part with details :

I am using `EGit` plugin in eclipse, and the problem was same as [OP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10457639/eclipse-compare-editor-stopped-showing-detailed-differences) - eclipse compare tool was not highlighting the differences **rather a whole block as if the whole file has changed.**

Lets understand the issue first , since I was aware that this is related to `CRLF` vs `LF` eol , so went to check that first and enabled the visibility as :

> Eclipse -> Preferences -> Text Editors -> Show whitespace characters
>   [image]

In the above click on **configure visibility**.

[image]

Now as you see highlighted in above image, select the check boxes under **Trailing** and against both `Carrier Return (CR)` and `Line Feed (LF)`.

Apply - Save and Close. Now in my case , file looked like this :

[image]

and this evident that for me I had `CRLF` window like eol which further also confirms as I do not have `core.autocrlf` set to `true` and by [default](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39408793/git-core-autocrlf-line-ending-default-setting) it is `false` thus `Git` actually didn't tried to do anything about my EOL delimiters (as expected in this case).

And until this stage, the compare tool was showing the whole file as changed.

Now, moving to fix which worked for me.

Since, I wanted to get this fix within IDE realm, thus I first converted the particular file to Unix delimiters as :
[image]

Then my file became with LF (Unix delimiter) eol :

[image]

**And compare tool started highlighting the delta.**

[image]

**So the issue as** it was assumed was because of `CRLF` (window style) eol and eclipse comparator was not able to highlight delta rather whole file.

Then, instead of changing each file or package to Unix delimiters . 
I updated in Eclipse->Preferences -> Workspace
[image]

By this, eclipse takes care of line-endings for new files to `Unix`, so that text files are saved in a format that is not specific to the Windows OS and most easily shared across heterogeneous developer desktops. After all this compare tool worked happily ever.

Hope this helps.

Comment: very useful information, it worked for me, eclipse compare tool is working as expected. @Vivek thanks