# Git text=auto core.autocrlf=false on Windows gives CRLFs

Tags: git

How is that possible?
I have a .gitattributes with the following content

```
* text=auto
```

UPDATE:
Huh. It turns out it's .gitattributes file that results in this behavior. Can somebody explain this or point to the relevant docs?

Answer (score 3):

After setting up a `.gitattributes`, use `git add --renormalize .` (from the directory that contains these `*.sh` and `*.bash` files) or `git add --renormalize *.sh *.bash` to update the files before committing.  Or, use `touch *.sh *.bash; git checkout -f *.sh *.bash` to update the work-tree copies.

#### What's going on here

As you no doubt already know, a Git repository contains *commits*.  Each commit has a frozen copy of each file that was committed, in exactly the state that it had when you (or whoever) committed it.  *This frozen copy can never be changed,* so if it has CRLF line endings, it has them forever, and if it has LF-only line endings, it has them forever.  Any *other* copy of that file, in any *other* future commit, can be different, but *this* copy in *this* commit is frozen.  (Any copy in any other existing commit is of course also frozen, but could be different.)

Internally, each committed file is in a special, Git-only format, compressed and usable only by Git—and once committed, frozen forever in that particular commit.  But of course, you can *look at* committed files, by extracting them; and you can make *new* committed files, working with the extracted files that you can modify.  Thus, Git needs two operations:

- copy a file *from* a commit, *to* where you can work on it; and
- copy a file *from* where you have worked on it, *to* (be ready for) a commit.

It is these two operations that actually do any CRLF-to-LF-only or vice versa.

The place that holds the versions of files that you work with and work on is, perhaps unsurprisingly, called the *work-tree* (or some variant of this such as *working tree* or *working directory*).  You use, and work on, files in your *work-tree*.  You tell Git to copy files *from* a commit, *to* the work-tree, or to copy files *from* the work-tree, *to* (be ready for) a commit.

#### The index

There's an extra wrinkle in the way here, and that is that Git doesn't make commits from what's in your work-tree at all.  Instead, Git inserts, between the commit and the work-tree, a third holding-area.  Git calls this the *index*, the *staging area*, or sometimes the *cache*, depending on who / which part of Git is doing the calling.

Files in the index are always *ready to be committed*.  That is, they have the same special, compressed, Git-only format that they would in a commit.  That's the trick that makes `git commit` so fast (compared to other version control systems anyway): everything is, at all times—or almost all times anyway—ready to go.  When you run `git commit`, Git doesn't even *look at* the work-tree.  It just packages up the files that are in the index, in the form they have now, all compressed and Git-ified and ready to go.

The `git add` command copies files *from* the work-tree, *into* the index, making them ready-to-go.  The `git checkout` command, by comparison, copies files *from* a commit—the one you're checking out—first into the index so that they're ready for the *next* commit, and then on into the work-tree.

#### This is why you need `git add --renormalize`

Suppose that some file is stored, in some way (with or without CRLF endings), in a commit.  You run `git checkout name` to pick a branch and its tip commit.  The files in that commit go into the index, and from there to the work-tree.  The copy-out step—index to work-tree—changes the files to have the line endings someone told Git to use, probably through a `.gitattributes` file in the commit you just checked out.

If those are *wrong*, you now change the `.gitattributes` file.<sup>1</sup>  This would, perhaps, change the way the files *should* be in the next commit.  It would, perhaps, change the way the files *should* be in the work-tree.  But—here's the problem—**Git already has the files the way it thinks is right, in both the index and the work-tree.**

Moreover, here's the *worse* problem: **Not only does Git have the files the way it thinks is right, it also thinks it doesn't need to do any new work with them.**  If you run `git checkout` or `git add` on them right now, Git cleverly notices that the work-tree copies have not been touched and *does nothing*, even though a re-checkout or re-add would do something different!

The result is that you have to, in effect, *trick* Git into redoing work.  If you need some or all work-tree files updated according to the "from index to work-tree" sequence, you can, for each such file:

- *remove* the work-tree copy and run `git checkout` again, or
- `touch` the work-tree copy (so that Git thinks you've modified it) and run `git checkout -f` to force-overwrite them.

If you need some or all work-tree files updated according to the "from work-tree to index" sequence, you can:

- `touch` the work-tree copy (so that Git thinks you've modified it) and run `git add`, or
- use the new-ish `git add --renormalize` to force Git to re-add the files even though it can see that you haven't touched them.

If your Git is too old to have `git add --renormalize`, you can use the `touch` method.

---

<sup>1</sup>This all holds for `core.autocrlf` and `core.eol` as well, but it's almost always best to use the `.gitattributes` file for finer control here.  The Git maintainers do this for Git itself, for instance.

Comment: Thank you for your time writing this answer. It might be useful for somebody. But I'm not sure it explains my issue. I managed to reproduce it with the following actions: 1) create a new repo 2) set autocrlf to 'input' 3) commit some file 4) observe its endings are not changed when switching autocrlf to 'false', deleting and checking out the file 5) commit .gitattributes shown above 6) repeat 2 and 4 and observe the endings do change this time

Comment: Try doing what I suggested: `git add --renormalize`. (Note: I don't have Windows myself, I can at best emulate it on MacOS / Linux etc.) If you edit your six steps into a script someone can run, and put that into your question, that will help the someone-else reproduce your issue.

Comment: (Since I am not using Windows, if I try your steps 1-4, at step 4 I get exactly what I would expect: a file that has LF-only line endings, and there are no issues from here on out because the file should and does always have LF-only line endings. See also https://stackoverflow.com/q/39408793/1256452)

Comment: after running `git add --renormalize .` `git status` is `nothing to commit, working tree clean`

Comment: Hm, OK. I also see that you took out the `eol=lf` that you had in the first couple of versions of the question. I assume that you wanted, and had, CRLF line endings initially, because setting `core.autocrlf = input` tells Git to do only the work-tree-to-index-copy line-ending changes. (Other systems would want and have LF-only endings initially.) Setting `eol=lf` in `.gitattributes` also sets the work-tree-to-index conversion, which `git add --renormalize` should obey. Meanwhile `* text=auto` should have *no* effect as `text=auto` is the default. So this seems puzzling.

Comment: I removed what was irrelevant (I checked). It's `* text=auto` that causes trouble. I think it might be a bug.

Comment: Yes, that definitely sounds like a bug. If so, the specific Python version is probably important (I'd recommend adding that to the question). (It's probably also a good idea to check that your files are being saved in UTF-8 rather than UTF-16, but either way that should still not affect the automatic classification.)

Answer (score 0):

The git documentation is vague about how `core.autocrlf` and .gitattributes play together:

> text
>
> This attribute enables and controls end-of-line normalization. When a text file is normalized, its line endings are converted to LF in the repository. To control what line ending style is used in the working directory, use the eol attribute for a single file and the core.eol configuration variable for all text files. Note that core.autocrlf overrides core.eol

What do they mean by `Note that core.autocrlf overrides core.eol` if we have the following

> core.eol
>
> Sets the line ending type to use in the working directory for files that have the text property set when core.autocrlf is false. Alternatives are lf, crlf and native, which uses the platform’s native line ending. The default value is native. See gitattributes[5] for more information on end-of-line conversion.

This statement says that what I'm seeing is an **expected behavior** since `core.eol` is `native` by default and I have `core.autocrlf=false`.

**UPDATE:**
This is indeed an expected behavior, `core.eol` applies only to files with `text` git attribute set and when `autocrlf=false`. One can say that with `autocrlf=false` `* text=auto` *triggers* automatic line ending conversion (on Windows with default `core.eol` the result is the same as `autocrlf=true`).

The documentation is vague, but it will probably be improved soon.

Comment: I do not think it is the expected behavior. After reading your question, I searched the [docs](https://git-scm.com/docs/gitattributes#_checking_out_and_checking_in) myself last night. Your `*text=auto` is a specific option of adding git attributes and should convert your line endings to lf. From what I gather, the only case you would see crlf, is if you had already commited the file with `crlf` before changing your configuration (to `auto.crlf=false`, `*text=auto`) and then you didn't commit any changes after that (only checked out).

Comment: "One can say that with `autocrlf=false` `* text=auto` triggers automatic line ending conversion".  Actually, one can say that `* text=auto` triggers automatic line ending conversion regardless of `core.autocrlf`.  It's explicitly there to override `core.autocrlf`.

Comment: @EdwardThomson `auto` enables input and output conversion. But for output, it's `core.eol` or `core.autocrlf` (if not false) that determines the separator used.

Comment: You shouldn't use the configuration settings, you should check in your configuration using `.gitattributes`.  If you want to set a specific line ending, set the `eol` attribute.