# Egit detects tab chars as changed

Tags: eclipse, diff, egit

I'm using Eclipse + EGit, and every time I make a commit, Egit detect tab chars as changed:

[image]

but I don't change anything on that part of the code. Tab chars are tab chars, and are not replaced by whitespaces.

Any idea ?

Comment: It looks more likely that the newline characters have changed. Use "Show Whitespace Characters" from the context menu to see them.

Comment: @robinst but it only happens on tab chars. Other lines without tab chars don't show as changed.

Comment: So, have you tried "Show Whitespace Characters"?

Comment: possible duplicate of [The is nothing changed, but eclipse egit keep to marked the file as changed](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8227233/the-is-nothing-changed-but-eclipse-egit-keep-to-marked-the-file-as-changed)

Answer (score 0):

You may have some auto formatter active, which replaces tabs by blanks or the other way around. This may not really be visible in the editor on first glance, as the editor can display a tab character the same as the respective number of blanks. You may want to store the original file and the edited one separately outside Eclipse to compare them in another editor.

However, you can ignore whitespace changes in the compare view at least. I'm not sure of your version, for me that is a toolbar button in the main toolbar. You can press Ctrl-3 and enter "Ignore" to see, if that command is available for you.

Comment: To ignore whitespace from comparison, you can set the value in Window > Preferences > General > Compare/Patch > Ignore white space