# Why eclipse thinks something has changed in my local git repository?

Tags: eclipse, egit

this is a issue I've been bumping into lately. Eclipse shows > on some of my project files marking them as changed even though they're actually not. Running git status in git bash shows no changes and comparing to a latest revision through eclipse shows no changes too.

What might be a cause for that?

Comment: See this: http://stackoverflow.com/q/8227233/1700321 and that: http://stackoverflow.com/q/1510798/1700321.

Answer (score 0):

You can see the list of changed files.

Right click on the project > Team > Commit...

In the files section you should see the list of changed files.

Comment: yes, but the problem is that these files are not actually changed. if you run git status on your repo it shows that everything is up to date

Comment: Assuming you updated your Eclipse git plugin to the latest version. So that we can be sure it is not a bug in the git plugin. Git can ignore all file mode changes: git config core.fileMode false