# Github shows diff for the same content

Tags: java, eclipse, git, maven, github

I've recently forked a repository. I made a local repository and created a maven project through eclipse. I made the changes I wanted and commited them. Although I made minor changes the differences shown on `Github` are tremendous. All the file is shown as having been changed. I believe that this is an encoding misalignment. In my eclipse workspace I didn't change anything when I created the project so the default was `Cp1253` (Windows 7).

I want to make a pull request for the changes I made, but I want to fix this diff problem before I do that. I don't know what encoding was used in the original project. What are my options?

Comment: even a file permissions changes are also shown as all files changed.

Comment: I didn't know that. Although I didn't mess with any of that.

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/q/8227233/1700321 and http://stackoverflow.com/q/1510798/1700321.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check your `.gitconfig` file in your home directory. Do you have the following setting?

```
[core]
    autocrlf = input
```

Comment: If you mean the config file inside the .git folder, then no. I added that, but still... how will the diffs from past commits will be fixed? More importantly, can they be fixed, or should I just recreate the repository, add this option and see what happens?

Comment: You can add this on a per project basis, but there should be a global one at ``~/.gitconfig``. But the one in the project overrides the global one. What happens if you do a fresh clone? Do you have any changes right from the beginning? And are you already using Git 2?

Comment: Just clone the same repository in a new location and see, if it already has any changes