# Eclipse GIT plugin shows differences that don't exist

Tags: eclipse, git, egit, git-diff

I'm using Eclipse GIT plugin (EGIT) to compare the entire master branch with another branch ("Compare With-->With branch, tag or reference)". The synchronize view shows many conflicts (with red double-arrows) but these files are absolutely equals (opening the text compare editor shows no text differences, no withespace differences or new-line char differences).

By the way, the command line tool "git diff master branch1" shows that the two projects are absolutely equals.

Why do EGIT and GIT command line have different behaviour?

My Eclipse is Luna Service Release 1 (4.4.1) Build id: 20140925-1800.
My EGIT plugin is 3.4.1.201406201815-r

Thanks

Comment: possible duplicate of [There is nothing changed, but eclipse egit marks the file as changed](http://stackoverflow.com/q/8227233/1700321)

Comment: Hi Aleksandr, it is not the same problem. The question you are linked is related to a text-compare problem (line endings). In my case eclipse text compare shows that my files are identical, the problem is in the tree-compare section.

Comment: I've removed the close vote, but it still can be the line endings problem.