# Eclipse - change spacing between filenames in project explorer

Tags: eclipse

I don't know why there is more (too much for me) spacing between tracked file names or folder names (Git), as opposed to untracked file names or folder names in my Eclipse project explorer, as seen in the following screenshot.

I would like the same spacing for tracked files and untracked files.

I looked at eclipse/plugins/org.eclipse.ui.themes_1.2.400.v20190223-1254/css/e4_default_gtk.css but I don't see where I can make the change.

Thanks for your help.

I use Eclipse 2019-03 on Linux (Gnome, GTK3)

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can try this,

Help -> Installation Details -> Installation History and revert back to previous version.

You can do this to track down *which* theme / particular installation is causing you this issue and remove it off!

Hope this helps!

Comment: I tried every Eclipse theme or rollback but this is not fixing the issue

Answer (score 0):

Please see https://www.eclipse.org/forums/index.php/t/82487/ and check the last few posts in the forum.

Good luck,
K3

Answer (score -1):

This is a bug, but you can try this:

- Run `git config --global core.autocrlf true` on your local GIT repository
- Read https://www.eclipse.org/forums/index.php/t/367532/
- and [There is nothing changed, but eclipse egit marks the file as changed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8227233/there-is-nothing-changed-but-eclipse-egit-marks-the-file-as-changed)

I hope any of this can help you!

Best regards, Brhaka

Comment: You are not responding to my question, the link you are referring to are for other problems, this is not fixing my issue